# Need correction

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

Whats wrong with this query.

```
 with tt AS
    ( select   
    f.stdcode,
                 f.name,
                 f.fname,
                 f.degree_code,
                 f.interdegree,
                 MIN(f.startsem)as startsemdate,
                 MAX(f.startsem)as endsemedate
    FROM v_interstudata f
    GROUP BY 
      f.stdcode,
                 f.name,
                 f.fname,
                 f.degree_code,
                 f.interdegree
                )
    select   
    tt.stdcode,
      tt.name,
      tt.fname,
      tt.degree_code,
      tt.interdegree,
      (select sem_code 
             from v_interstudata a
            where a.stdcode=tt.stdcode 
             and a.startsem=tt.startsemdate) startsemester
      from tt
```

Here is a link for sample data in excel file 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zf3ayRW_G_QR7lHY41kZqMdhHUQ-k_TK_u9O2IQjGkU
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9Z6e.png)

Comment: What don't you understand about the error?

Comment: Share the sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a `JOIN` for this.  You can use `KEEP`:

```
SELECT f.stdcode, f.name, f.fname, f.degree_code,  f.interdegree,
       MIN(f.startsem)as startsemdate,
       MAX(f.startsem)as endsemedate,
       MIN(sem_code) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY startsem ASC) as first_sem_code,
       MIN(sem_code) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY startsem DESC) as last_sem_code
FROM v_interstudata f
GROUP BY f.stdcode, f.name, f.fname, f.degree_code,  f.interdegree
```

Comment: This may not give the same output; the OP has correlated the sub-queries on only `stdcode` and `startsem` however this query correlates the `KEEP DENSE_RANK FIRST` values on all the `GROUP BY` terms and by `startsem`.

Comment: @MT0 . . . That is true, but the OP's query doesn't work.  I should add that I think this is what the OP wants.

Comment: @NaseebUlHassan . . . (1) That is not the question you have asked here.  (2) Then you have duplicates in your data.  I would advise you to ask a NEW question.  Provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zf3ayRW_G_QR7lHY41kZqMdhHUQ-k_TK_u9O2IQjGkU   here is a link for sample data

Comment: also link attached for your convenience download the data.

Answer (score 1):

One (or both) of these subqueries:

```
  (select sem_code 
         from v_interstudata a
        where a.stdcode=tt.stdcode 
         and a.startsem=tt.startsemdate) startsemester,
  --
  (select sem_code
         from v_interstudata a
         where a.stdcode=tt.stdcode 
        and a.startsem=tt.endsemedate) endsemester
```

return more than a single value so Oracle complains about it.

What to do? Well, if you can include additional condition(s) which will restrict number of rows to `1`, do so.

I don't know how experienced Oracle (or SQL) user you are, but - if you don't know it very well (yet), consider not to use such constructions. You'd rather try to use joins to retrieve data you need.